# How to express this tensor compute with numpy?

Tags: numpy, neural-network, linear-algebra

Suppose that `x` is a vector with shape `(a,)`, `T` is a tensor with shape `(b, a, a)`.
If I want to compute `(x^T)Tx` ,I can do it using `x.dot(w.dot(x).transpose())`.

For example:

```
x = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.])

w = np.array([[[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
               [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
               [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.]],
              [[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
               [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
               [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.]]])

x.dot(w.dot(x).transpose())
```

But what if I want to decompose `T` into two tensors `P` and `Q` (low rank express) with shape `(b,a,r)` and `(b,r,a)` and `r<<a`  so each matrix in `T` which is `a*a` decomposed to `a*r` and `r*a`， which reduce much data. Then how do I do the computation of `(x^T)PQx` with numpy?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute `P` and `Q` or how to use them in `(x^T)PQx`?

Comment: The latter one.  Given x,P,Q, how to compute (x^T)PQx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has problems.

```
x.shape  (5,)
w.shape  (2,3,5)
x.dot(w.dot(x).transpose())
   ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

But to use your description:

```
`x` `(a,)`,  `T` `(b,a,a)`; `(x^T)Tx`
```

I like to use `einsum` (Einstein summation) when thinking about complex products.  I think your `x'Tx` is:

```
np.einsum('i,kij,j->k', x, T, x)
```

T decomposed into: `P` `(b,a,r)`, `Q` `(b,r,a)`;

```
np.einsum('kir,krj->kij', P,Q) == T
```

together the expressions are:

```
np.einsum('i,kir,krj,j->k', x, P, Q, x)
```

`einsum` isn't the best when the dimensions are large, since the combined iteration space of `k,i,j,r` may be large.  Still it is a useful way to think about the problem.

I think it can be rewritten as 3 `dots`:

```
P1 = np.einsum('i,kir->kr', x, P)
Q1 = np.einsum('krj,j->kr', Q, x)
np.einsum('kr,kr->k', P1, Q1)
```

---

A sample calculation:

```
In [629]: a,b,r = 5,3,2
In [630]: x=np.arange(1.,a+1)
In [632]: P=np.arange(b*a*r).reshape(b,a,r)
In [633]: Q=np.arange(b*a*r).reshape(b,r,a)

In [635]: T=np.einsum('kir,krj->kij',P,Q)

In [636]: P
Out[636]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        ...
        [24, 25],
        [26, 27],
        [28, 29]]])

In [637]: Q
Out[637]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]],
        ...
       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])

In [638]: T
Out[638]: 
array([[[   5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
        [  15,   20,   25,   30,   35],
        [  25,   34,   43,   52,   61],
        [  35,   48,   61,   74,   87],
        ...
        [1105, 1154, 1203, 1252, 1301],
        [1195, 1248, 1301, 1354, 1407],
        [1285, 1342, 1399, 1456, 1513]]])

In [639]: T.shape
Out[639]: (3, 5, 5)

In [640]: R1=np.einsum('i,kij,j->k',x,T,x)
...
In [642]: R1
Out[642]: array([  14125.,  108625.,  293125.])

In [643]: R2=np.einsum('i,kir,krj,j->k',x,P,Q,x)
In [644]: R2
Out[644]: array([  14125.,  108625.,  293125.])

In [645]: P1=np.einsum('i,kir->kr',x,P)
In [646]: Q1=np.einsum('krj,j->kr',Q,x)
In [647]: R3=np.einsum('kr,kr->k',P1,Q1)
In [648]: R3
Out[648]: array([  14125.,  108625.,  293125.])

In [649]: P1
Out[649]: 
array([[  80.,   95.],
       [ 230.,  245.],
       [ 380.,  395.]])

In [650]: Q1
Out[650]: 
array([[  40.,  115.],
       [ 190.,  265.],
       [ 340.,  415.]])
```

The last set of calculations can be done with `dot`

```
In [656]: np.dot(x,P)
Out[656]: 
array([[  80.,   95.],
       [ 230.,  245.],
       [ 380.,  395.]])

In [657]: np.dot(Q,x)
Out[657]: 
array([[  40.,  115.],
       [ 190.,  265.],
       [ 340.,  415.]])

In [658]: np.dot(np.dot(x,P),np.dot(Q,x).T)
Out[658]: 
array([[  14125.,   40375.,   66625.],
       [  37375.,  108625.,  179875.],
       [  60625.,  176875.,  293125.]])
```

But we want just the diagonal of the last `dot`.  A simpler sum of products is better:

```
In [661]: (P1*Q1).sum(axis=1)
Out[661]: array([  14125.,  108625.,  293125.])
```